How do I perfectly center a square SVG within a square button?
NOTE: this question was closed as a duplicate of this question about centering text within a div block. My question is about centering an SVG within a button. Buttons apparently have a lot of hidden properties that make this much more difficult than centering inside a simple div.
I tried using this solution to help me center a square SVG within a square button (horizontally and vertically, of course). The main differences is that, in the solution, the coordinate system of the SVG viewBox is different (but still square). Also, I specify a width and height for the button (still square, though). The solution demonstrated that styling the search-button with padding: 0 fixed the problem.
For me, though, the SVG is clearly nearer the top than the bottom, as the red outline shows. (It also may be nearer the left than the right, but that could be an optical illusion.)
I've tried to eliminate all non-essential styling from this example. What is needed to coerce the SVG to be perfectly centered inside the button?


#search-button {
    align-items: center;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    padding: 0; /* one solution used this */
}
#search-button-svg {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}
<button type="submit" id="search-button">
   <svg id="search-button-svg"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        viewBox="0 0 512 512">
     <path d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40
         122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 
         45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3
         0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 
         40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0
         208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 
         352a144 144 0 1 0
         0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/>
   </svg>
</button>




Use flex on button, or calc(size - x) x=button's border(px) padding, margin...

What browser are you using? Safari on IOS is even less centered. Different browsers style buttons different ways so you may need to remove all potential styling before starting again.

This shouldn't be linked to centering text in a div. For buttons with SVG you want to be able to set the size w/h on the button and padding:0, that is 3 lines of CSS for the button, and the SVG be 100% Which it is by default so no CSS on the SVG required when you set the inert attribute on the SVG https://jsfiddle.net/WebComponents/9143afeL/ (I don't know if Sarari does this different, should be a bug then) Size/pad the SVG with SVG, not with CSS

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman I don't know what you mean about linking to centered text in a div.

Your question is closed by Paulie with a link to another SO question about centering text in a div

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman Agree. As you say, this is about buttons with SVG, not text in a div.

Set the SVG to display block and then replace the widht and the height on the button with a margin in the SVG.


#search-button {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#search-button-svg {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  display: block;
  margin: calc(.5em - 2px); /* subtract the width of the border of the button */
}
<button type="submit" id="search-button">
   <svg id="search-button-svg"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        viewBox="0 0 512 512">
     <path d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40
         122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 
         45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3
         0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 
         40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0
         208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 
         352a144 144 0 1 0
         0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/>
   </svg>
</button>




This seems fine on Edge/Chrome but on IOS Safari the button ends up wider that its height.

Bugger... The button is already display inline-block as default -- does it help to set the margin to zero? @AHaworth

@chrwahl: You can fix this iOS safari issue by adding a -webkit-appearance:none property to the button. The described padding is related to safaris default button styles

@chrwahl The above suggestion -webkit-appearance: none does seem to fix the iOS Safari issue. What is it about your solution that causes your button to render slightly larger than the other solutions (in desktop browsers)?

@Chap it is the border of the button that makes the difference. In the example I now subtract 2px from the border of the SVG, so that the button ends up being 2em in width and height.

Make sure the line-height within the button is also zero.


#search-button {
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#search-button > svg {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
}
<button type="submit" id="search-button">
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M416 208c0 46-15 88-40 123l127 126a32 32 0 0 1-46 46L331 376a208 208 0 1 1 85-168zM208 352a144 144 0 1 0 0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/></svg>
</button>




This seems fine on Edge/Chrome but on Safari IOS the svg is slightly outside the button.

I could not get the suggested flex to work, and note that your align-items has no effect in the code you have given.
Instead this snippet resorts to the old fashioned positioning with translate, setting the svg to position: absolute so it has no effect on the button.


#search-button {
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  padding: 0;
  /* one solution used this */
  position: relative;
}

#search-button-svg {
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 2em;
  height: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
<button type="submit" id="search-button">
   <svg id="search-button-svg"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        viewBox="0 0 512 512">
     <path d="M416 208c0 45.9-14.9 88.3-40
         122.7L502.6 457.4c12.5 12.5 12.5 32.8 0 
         45.3s-32.8 12.5-45.3
         0L330.7 376c-34.4 25.2-76.8 40-122.7 
         40C93.1 416 0 322.9 0
         208S93.1 0 208 0S416 93.1 416 208zM208 
         352a144 144 0 1 0
         0-288 144 144 0 1 0 0 288z"/>
   </svg>
</button>




Just to note that this was the only method I could find which gave a sensible look on Safari IOS, where the default styling of a button differs from Chrome/Edge’s on e.g. Windows.
